# bind two fields in the client template for a kendo grid column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I get an InvalidOperationException with a message saying:

> bound columns require a field or property access expression

My razor markup goes like this:

```
(@Html.Kendo().Grid<StackInfo>()
            .Columns(col =>
            {
                col.Bound(e => e.FileID).Title("ID");
                col.Bound(e => e.Name).Title("Filename");
                col.Bound(e => e.Status);

                col.Bound(e => new { Status = e.Status, FileID = e.FileID }).ClientTemplate("#if(Status == 'new') {#"
                    + "<a href=\"View?TaskID=#FileID#\">View</a>"
                    + "#} else {#"
                    + "<a href=\"Open?TaskID=#FileID#\">Open</a>"
                    + "#} #").Title(string.Empty);
            })
            .AutoBind(false)
            .DataSource(ds => ds
                .Ajax()
                .Read(r => r.Action("Tasks_Read", "Task"))
                .PageSize(10)
                )
            .Pageable()
            .Name("tasksGrid")
            .Scrollable(k => k.Height(205)))
```

What I am trying to accomplish is that the grid will show an extra column; it furnishes a link, whose action is actually based on the value in the Status field. Hence I've written my ClientTemplate like so.

However I get an exception at that line. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is in `.Bound(e => new { Status = e.Status, FileID = e.FileID })` of your fourth column. Try this code:

```
columns.Template(@<text></text>)
    .ClientTemplate("#if(Status == 'new') {#"
                + "<a href=\"View?TaskID=#FileID#\">View</a>"
                + "#} else {#"
                + "<a href=\"Open?TaskID=#FileID#\">Open</a>"
                + "#} #").Title(string.Empty);
```

Comment: Hi @Jaroslaw. When I use your example, the template does not render the #FileID# field's value. (Well in my case the field is called something else).
The template  
.ClientTemplate("#if (IsChecked == true) {#<a onclick='printImages(#IsChecked#)' href='\\#'></a>#}#").Width(70).Title("col3");  
renders as  
<a onclick="printContainer()" href="#"></a>

Comment: Try to use `#: #` template istead of `# #` to render values. You can mix it like in this example: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview (last code example on this site)

Comment: The code I'm working in already has the grid wrapped in a `<text>` Element, so it errored out until I replaced it with a random property to bind it to (i.e. `.Template(e => e.Name)`).  I'm still not clear on what the purpose of `Template()` is for, other than I need it to invoke `ClientTemplate()`.  I agree with @JarosławKończak about adding the Colon (but only if you want to Html-Encode your values to show the Markup instead of rendering it - if you have additional Html in your Parameters that you want rendered, then leave the colon out).  This is a great example of adding AdHoc Javascript.